# Asymptotic relationship between tests of compact composite nulls and one sided tests

Tags: hypothesis-testing, asymptotics, composite

**A motivating example**

Let $x_t\sim N(\mu,1)$ for $t=1,\dots,T$. Consider testing the null $H_0: \mu\in[-1,1]$ against the alternative $H_1:\mu\in\mathbb{R}\setminus [-1,1]$.

The natural (UMPU?) test rejects when $|\hat{\mu}|$ is large.

Note that if $\mu\ne 0$ as $T\rightarrow \infty$, the distribution of $|\hat{\mu}|$ converges to the distribution of $(\operatorname{sgn}{\mu})\hat{\mu}$ as $\Pr(\operatorname{sgn}{\mu}\ne\operatorname{sgn}{\hat\mu}|\mu)\rightarrow 0$, so progressively less mass is getting "reflected" to the opposite sign. (Caveat: this convergence is not uniform in $\mu$.) Thus, for any fixed $\mu$, the following test has asymptotically identical size and power: if $\hat{\mu}>0$ then run a one sided test of $H_0^+:\mu\le 1$ vs $H_1^+:\mu>1$, if $\hat{\mu}<0$ then run a one sided test of $H_0^-:\mu\ge -1$ vs $H_1^-:\mu<-1$, and if $\hat{\mu}=0$ then fail to reject.

This alternative test can be considered as a "plug-in" procedure. We "plug-in" an estimate of the nuisance parameter (here $\operatorname{sgn}{\mu}$) and then use the optimal test conditional on that estimate of the nuisance parameter being correct.

**A possible generalisation**

Now consider testing $H_0:\theta\in\Theta\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ against $H_1:\theta\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\Theta$, where $\Theta$ is a compact set which is equal to the closure of its interior.

Is it the case that for any (reasonable?) test of this hypothesis, and any fixed $\theta\in\mathbb{R}^n$, there is some $\nu\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\kappa\in\mathbb{R}$ (both potentially a function of $\hat\theta$) such that the test has asymptotically the same size and power as a test of $\tilde{H}_0:\nu'\theta\le \kappa$ vs $\tilde{H}_1:\nu'\theta > \kappa$? How do we find $\nu$ and $\kappa$? Is $\nu$ a normal to a tangent of $\Theta$ at a point "closest" to $\hat\theta$? Do we need asymptotic normality of $\theta$?

Additional question: does the non-uniform convergence matter? In the initial example, convergence is slowest when $\mu\approx 0$. But then $\hat\mu\approx 0$, so we are likely to fail to reject anyway in large samples.

Comment: This seems to be an exercise in frequentist math stat.  Simple Bayesian methods would cut through all of that and avoid the need to appeal to asymptotics.

Comment: Is math.stackexchange more appropriate for frequentist questions these days?

Comment: No, frequentist questions are entirely appropriate here. You're asking about [equivalence tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_test), right? We have a relevant tag for that (and a number of related questions)

Comment: I hadn't heard that term before. But isn't this the complement of an equivalence test? The null here is a convex set, with the alternative being non-convex, whereas it seems that an equivalence test has a convex alternative.

Comment: I think this line of inquiry may be doomed. You make an overly strong implicit assumption about what each $\theta$ represents.  Especially in multivariate settings, the convexity of $\Theta$ may be nearly meaningless and will guarantee little. After all, many tests--think of ML--will not change (or not asymptotically change) under a continuous reparameterization.  In your motivating example the new parameter still lies within an interval--a convex set--but that is not longer the case in higher dimensions.

Comment: Maybe requiring convexity was a mistake. It is certainly not needed for the boundary of the null to look locally like a hyperplane.

Comment: Welcome to CV, cfp! You may find this an interesting resource in application of these kinds of tests: Wellek, S. (2010). *Testing Statistical Hypotheses of Equivalence and Noninferiority* (Second ed.). Chapman and Hall/CRC Press.

Comment: Thanks for the reference!

Comment: @Alexis However, as I said before, this is not an equivalence test. Equivalence tests have non-compact nulls.

Comment: Oh! I see: I switched your null and alternative in my head. You want to provide a test for a difference with a magnitude *at least as large* as 1? Chapter 11 of the  Wellek text does have a chapter on **tests for relevant difference** which I *think* is closely aligned with what you are after?

Comment: For example, the chapter opens with "Thus, in a generic formulation, all problems to be considered in this chapter read  $H_{∗}: \theta \in [\theta_{◦} - \varepsilon_{1} , \theta_{◦} + \varepsilon_{2}]$ versus $K_{∗}: \theta < \theta_{◦} − \varepsilon_{1} \vee \theta > \theta_{◦} + \varepsilon_{1}$".

Comment: Finally tracked down this book. Unfortunately, that chapter is not a great deal of help. It just gives details on construction of critical regions for a few specific "relevant difference" tests.